# weak convergence to point mass and unbounded functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\nu_n$ be a sequence of probability measures converging weakly to a Dirac measure at $x$. This implies that for all bounded continuous functions f, $\nu_n(f)$ converges to $f(x)$. Are there any conditions on $\nu_n$ such that this holds also for some unbounded test function $f$?
In particular cases I guess this is possible: e.g. $\nu_n$ are some Gaussian shrinking to their mean $x$, then basically $f(y)=y$ always work. Is there something less specific than this?